# Erlang ** exception error: no function clause matching

Tags: parsing, exception, erlang

Hi guys I have the makings of a parser for a Theorem Prover. I have a module which previously tokenises the string so im inputting: [{bracket,open},{prop,a},{logicOp,'and'},{prop,b},{bracket,close}] to a parser which has an calls an inner function. here is the code:

```
parse([])-> [];
parse(FullList) ->
    parseClauses(FullList,[],[]).


parseClauses([{bracket, open}| RestOfList], StackList, ParsedList) ->
    parseClauses(RestOfList, 
            StackList ++ [{bracket, open}], 
                ParsedList);

parseClauses([{prop, Any},{logicOp, Any}| RestOfList], StackList, ParsedList) ->
    parseClauses(RestOfList, 
             StackList ++ [{logicOp, Any},{prop, Any}], 
                ParsedList);

parseClauses([{bracket, close}, {logicOp, Any}| RestOfList],StackList,ParsedList) ->
    parseClauses(RestOfList, 
             StackList ++ [{bracket, close}], 
                [{logicOp, Any}] ++ ParsedList);

parseClauses([{bracket, close}|RestOfList], StackList, ParsedList) ->
    parseClauses(RestOfList,
                    StackList++[{bracket, close}],
                        ParsedList);

parseClauses([], Stack, Parsed) ->  Parsed ++ Stack.
```

run the code on terminal like so and get error:

```
tokeniser:parse([{bracket,open},
    {prop,a},
    {logicOp,'and'},
    {prop,b},
    {bracket,close}]).
** exception error: no function clause matching tokeniser:parseClauses([{prop,a},{logicOp,'and'},{prop,b},{bracket,close}],
                                       [{bracket,open}],
                                       [])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error message, you can tell that the function is being called like this:

```
tokeniser:parseClauses([{prop,a},{logicOp,'and'},{prop,b},{bracket,close}],
                                       [{bracket,open}],
                                       [])
```

This *almost* matches this clause:

```
parseClauses([{prop, Any},{logicOp, Any}| RestOfList], StackList, ParsedList) ->
```

But since `Any` is used twice in the argument list, this clause only matches when the two values are the same. In this call, they are different: `a` and `'and'`.

You could change the two occurences of `Any` to something else, e.g. `Prop` and `LogicOp`, and the clause would accept two different values.

Comment: Thanks @legoscia your good nature  in taking the time to answer my question has saved some of my hair from being pulled out :)